# Getting Error When running VTune GUI on an Ubuntu Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, intel, intel-oneapi, intel-vtune

I am using Intel VTune Profiler 2022.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I  running VTune GUI successfully on an Ubuntu VM using VMWare Fusion on Mac OS X Monterey.

Then, I installed the kernel debug symbol packages (linux-image-5.4.0-107-generic-dbgsym) using apt-get because I got error that I don't have kernel debug packages.

```html
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ vtune-gui
[2414:0415/122324.136712:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] renderergl_utils.cpp:188 (ClearErrors): Preexisting GL error 0x00000500 as of ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/gl/TextureGL.cpp, setImageHelper:256. 
[2381:0415/122327.011769:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(104)] AiaRequest::OnFetchCompleted got error -301
[2381:0415/122327.121572:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(104)] AiaRequest::OnFetchCompleted got error -301
[2381:0415/122327.157548:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(104)] AiaRequest::OnFetchCompleted got error -301
```

How I can fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use-case in which you are running VTune is not a supported platform or environment. VTune can only work with full functionality on Linux or Windows virtual guest machines running inside Linux or Windows host machines.Virtual machine inside macOS is not a supported platform for VTune profiler. You can read more regarding the virtual machine targets and the corresponding supported hypervisors in the links below:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/set-up-analysis-target/...
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/set-up-analysis-target/...

We recommend you switch to a supported host or guest system to ensure full functionality and error-free operation of VTune.